# Unable to create file in Android app

Tags: android, file-handling

I am making a android app in which i am going to use File handling but to do that first i need to create it but by using following code:

```
File logf = new File("log1.txt");
Boolean bb = logf.exists();
if(!bb)
try {
bb = logf.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
msg.setText("not able to create file.");
}
```

'msg' is the TextView object which i am using to display error, and when i run this app.. it goes into IOException e catch.. Please tell me if i am doing something wrong or what?.. besides i am using Android 2.2 for my app.

Comment: What's the logcat telling you?

Comment: Share manifest?

Comment: as my previous textview was empty and when i run this.. then it changed to "not able to create file.".. that means its not creating a file and its going into catch

Comment: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest file

Comment: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE was necessary if i was using external storage as i am only using internal storage which private for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app storage, please try this:

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "file.txt");
```

Or if you want to append file name, try this:

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + "file.txt");
```

Comment: don't i have to use file separator between them?

Comment: No need, please see `public File(File parent, String child)`

Answer (score 1):

you need to provide absolute path of file like below.

```
File file = new File(/data/packagename/files/ + "log1.txt");
```

Comment: but i am not using external storage, i want to use internal storage

Comment: rust fisher's was easy.. but yours is necessary when we have to share with apps